# Adding new values to a partitioned dataset Pyarrow

Tags: python, apache-spark, hdfs, parquet, pyarrow

I have a dataset as follows with the following columns: PARK, md, powerBy, value

With the following code we save the dataset in HDFS partitioning by the column PARK:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow as pa 

df = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv')


table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df,preserve_index=False)

fs = pa.hdfs.connect(host=HDFS_HOST, port=HDFS_PORT, user=HDFS_USER)


pq.write_to_dataset(
    table,
    root_path='path/hdfs',
    partition_cols=['PARK'],
    flavor='spark',
    filesystem=fs
)
```

So far so good. Now, suppose I get another dataset, mycsv2.csv, with the same columns. How can I add this dataset to the previously made partition?

Comment: hi! interested by the answer as well! :)